# WCF Error: System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException:

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf, windows-server-2008

When I try to run a demo WCF Service Project (Windows 7 Enterprise Machine) I get the following:

```
> Please try changing the HTTP port to 8733 or running as Administrator.
System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/helloworld/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DatagramChannelDemuxer`2.OnOuterListenerOpen(ChannelDemuxerFilter filter, IChannelListener listener, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelListener`3.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.NegotiationTokenAuthenticator`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenAuthenticator.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocolFactory.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityListenerSettingsLifetimeManager.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenAuthenticator.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenAuthenticator.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityListenerSettingsLifetimeManager.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)
System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
```

At home it works, but at work it seems I might need some type of pemissions elevated. I have tried running VS as administrator and changing the port to 8733 but I still get the problem. Also in command promopt I tried "netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user", but got the error "url reservation add failed error 5" I'm thinking maybe admin needs to elevate some type of permission.

Here is service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloWorldService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Name
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string First;
        [DataMember]
        public string Last;
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorld
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(Name person);
    }

    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorld
    {
        #region IHelloWorldMembers
        public string SayHello(Name person)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello {0} {1}",
                person.First, person.Last);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8080/helloworld" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="ws" 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  contract="HelloWorldService.IHelloWorld"/>
        <endpoint address="basic" 
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                    contract="HelloWorldService.IHelloWorld"/>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8081/helloworld" 
                      binding="netTcpBinding" 
                      contract="HelloWorldService.IHelloWorld"/>
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <!--<identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>-->

        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Start by adding a [MCVE]

Comment: @cFrozenDeath it's really a simple service, but example provided.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
```

Try :

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=DOMAIN\user
```

In other terms, remove last part of uri

Reference :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms733768.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help everyone. The issue was that on my local machine I did not have Administrator Rights, although running VS or command prompt gives the option to "Run as Administrator",  on my PC I needed actual Administrator rights. I contacted the Windows Server Admins at my place and had them give me those rights to my local.

You can check yourself what type of user you are by going to Computer Management, Local Users, and in Groups, check Administrators and see if your LAN appears.